# Why is libbetter.so causing Fatal Exception on certain Android devices in production build?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-hermes, hermes-jms

Fatal Exception: could not delete: /data/user/0/com.package_name/lib-0/libbetter.so on production build

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.packageName.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: could not delete: /data/user/0/com.packageName/lib-0/libbetter.so

This issue is coming in the production build on Firebase crash analytics, but I'm unable to reproduce it.
As Firebase crash analytic information this issue is coming on the following android devices
Galaxy Note20 Ultra 5G (Android version 13)
OnePlus 9 5G (Android Version 12)

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.7",

Any faced the same issue? please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know why this issue is coming, I have not found information regarding this issue on the internet as well, can you please let me know, which file code you want to see? I can see this error in the firebase console.